# Is code run from Platform.runLater thread safe?

Tags: javafx

If I have code ran entirely from within `Platform.runLater`, is that code automatically thread safe?

My understanding is that code ran on `Platform.runLater` is ran on the JavaFX application thread, which there is only one.

For example if I manipulate an hash map entirely in `Plaform.runLater`, I don't have to worry about multiple threads, right?

Comment: no. this simply means that the code will execute in the fx application thread.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Whether or not using [`Platform#runLater(Runnable)`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/12/javafx.graphics/javafx/application/Platform.html#runLater(java.lang.Runnable)) is thread-safe is entirely dependent on how you use it. The example you give is you have a `Map` visible from a background thread but only ever manipulate it on the *JavaFX Application Thread* via `runLater`. Maybe something like:

```
// executing on background thread
Object newKey = ...;
Object newVal = ...;
Platform.runLater(() -> map.put(newKey, newVal));
```

This makes the `Map` "thread-safe" only from the point-of-view of the *JavaFX Application Thread*. If the background thread later attempts to read the `Map` (e.g. `map.get(newKey)`) there is no guarantee said thread will see the new entry. In other words, it may read `null` because the entry "doesn't exist" or it may read an old value if one was already present. You could of course fix this by reading on the *JavaFX Application Thread* as well:

```
Object val = CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> map.get(key), Platform::runLater).join();
```

Or even by waiting for the *JavaFX Application Thread* to finish writing to the `Map`:

```
CountDownLatch latch = new CountDownLatch(1);
Platform.runLater(() -> {
    // write to map
    latch.countDown();
});
latch.await();
// writes to map will be visible to background thread from here
```

That said, actions by the background thread that happened before the call to `runLater` will be visible to the *JavaFX Application Thread*. In other words, a *happens-before* relationship is created. When scheduling the `Runnable` to execute on the *JavaFX Application Thread* eventually some inter-thread communication must occur, which in turn requires synchronization in order to be thread-safe. Looking at the Windows implementation of JavaFX I can't say for certain what this synchronization looks like, however, because it appears to invoke a native method.